# One store view homepage going to 404 sporadically

Tags: magento-enterprise, 404-page

We have 2 store view, one french, one english. We use the store view code in the URL : www.website.com/fr/ and www.website.com/en/

For some reason, from time to time, /en/ returns a 404 until something is done. The problem never occured on /fr/.

When the problem is occuring, if I go to www.website.com/index.php/en/, I do not get the 404.

I tried executing : php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url and that usually clears the 404, until the next time.

I found 1 product with no title / no url, which I deleted.